# when I try to get address using geocoder, given a run time error of "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(failed, Failed, null)"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I try to get the location using dart plugin of "geolocation and geocode" using. but the code gives an error of "Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(failed, Failed, null)". how do I overcome it?

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

Future<String> getCurrentLocation() async {
  final location = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  String latitude =(location.latitude).toString();
  String longitude = (location.longitude).toString();
  String _center = latitude + "," + longitude;
  print(_center);
  final coordinates = await new Coordinates(location.latitude, location.longitude);
  var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);

  var first = addresses.first;
  print("${first.featureName} : ${first.addressLine}");
  return _center;
}
```

Comment: Try this `https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/flutter-geolocator-plugin`

Comment: I try these tutorials. but code gives the same error. Error - "PlatformException(ERROR_GEOCODING_COORDINATES, Service not Available, null)"

Comment: "Service not Available" indicates that an IOException occurred during the translation of the coordinates. According to the underlying Android SDK we are using this means "IOException is thrown if the network is unavailable or any other I/O problem occurs. **Try restart you phone and run flutter clean then try again.make sure the location service is turned on**

Comment: Thank you so much, Morbius Black you are correct. it works for me. 

Comment: No mention....@Dilrukshika Rajapakshe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your apikey and it will work:

```
 var addresses = await Geocoder.google ( '<---------YOUR APIKEY-------->' ).findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a key in Google Cloud Platform and enable the Geocoder API for it

Use:

```
await Geocoder.google(your_API_Key).findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```

Instead of:

```
await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
```